# Custom HashMap Implementation in java

Tags: java, hash-map

I implemented a `CustomHashMap` in Java, and would like to know if my approach is good or not.

Below I am sharing the complete code of my `CustomHashMap`:

CustomHashMap.java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Objects;
import com.custom.utils.*;

public class CustomHashMap<K, T> implements Iterable<Entity> {

    private static final int capacity_init = 10;
    static final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75f;
    private int indexCount = 0;

    Entity[] bucket = null;

    Entity[] bucketItr = null;

    public CustomHashMap() {
        init(capacity_init);
    }

    public CustomHashMap(int capacity) {
        init(capacity);
    }

    private void init(int intcapacity) {

        bucket = new Entity[intcapacity];
    }

    private int hash(Object key) {

        return key.hashCode() >> 1;
    }



    public void add(K key, T value) {

        int hashcode = hash(key);

        if(indexCount == bucket.length){
            Entity[] obj = bucket;
            int k = (int) (obj.length*2);
            bucket = new Entity[k];
            System.arraycopy(obj, 0, bucket, 0, indexCount-1);
        }

        if (bucket[hashcode] == null) {
            indexCount++;
            Entity head = new Entity(key, value, null);
            bucket[hashcode] = head;
        } else {
            Entity temp = bucket[hashcode];
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            Entity neEntity = new Entity(key, value, null);
            neEntity.next = temp;
            bucket[hashcode] = neEntity;

        }

        bucketItr = new Entity[bucket.length];
        System.arraycopy(bucket, 0, bucketItr, 0, bucket.length);

    }



    public T get(K key) {
        int hashcode = hash(key);
        if (bucket[hashcode] == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Entity temp = bucket[hashcode];
            while (temp != null) {

                if (temp.key.equals(key)) {
                    return (T) temp.value;
                }
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public void delete(K key) {
        int hashcode = hash(key);
        Entity deleteNode = bucket[hashcode];
        deleteNode = null;
        bucket[hashcode] = deleteNode;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Entity> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bucketItr = new Entity[indexCount];
        int entryCount = 0;
        for (Entity e : bucket) {

            if (Objects.nonNull(e)) {
                bucketItr[entryCount] = e;
                entryCount++;
            }

        }

        return new MapItr();
    }

    class MapItr implements Iterator<Entity> {

        int count = 0;
        Entity node = bucketItr[0];

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return count < bucketItr.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Entity next() {

            Entity result = null;

            if (hasNext()) {
                result = node;
                if ( Objects.nonNull(node) && node.next != null) {
                    node = node.next;
                } else {
                    count++;
                    if (count < bucketItr.length)
                        node = bucketItr[count];
                }

                return result;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Entity.java

```
public class Entity<K, T> {
    public K key;
    public T value;
    public Entity next;

    public Entity(K key, T value, Entity next) {

        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;

    }

}
```

Please suggest improvements and things which you feel I need to add to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my comments, in decreasing order of severity:

### 1) BUGS

1. Hash function: your hash function does not refer in any way to the bucket (changing) capacity.  The main problem with that is that the function may produce values that are outside of the index bounds of the bucket array (current function may even produce negative values) and then your `add()` method would throw an exception. but even if you protect from such cases, the function needs to refer to the current capacity in order to spread the values as evenly as possible across the buckets.
2. Load factor: The code does not refer to the `DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR`: nor does it allow the user to override this value, and more importantly, it doesn't consider this when deciding if the bucket array  needs to be enlarged.  In fact, the whole logic of this decision seems to me to be wrong: when all entries in the bucket are full, you decide to enlarge the size. so theoretically, on the 11th `add()` call, you would enlarge the size.  This logic needs to be redesigned and it needs to be based on the total number of `Entity` instances in all the buckets and of course on the load factor.

Note: depending on the hash function implementation, you may need to rehash the entire hash table because if the hash function depends on the capacity, then it may produce different results for existing keys when the capacity changes.  So, the simple `System.arraycopy()` might not suffice.  This is actually what is done in the JDK implementation.

### 2) Performance

1. Adding a new `Entity` to the linked list involves going through the entire list.  This seems inefficient.  Perhaps you can save the last node in a separate array that has same length as `bucket`?
2. The usage of `bucketItr` seems redundant.  First of all, you copy `bucket` into `bucketItr` every time `add()` is called.  `System.arraycopy()` is efficient but that doesn't mean it need not be used judiciously. Moreover, the first line in `iterator()` initializes `bucketItr` from scratch, making the copy operation in `add()` completely redundant. but moreover, I don't see the reason for this array at all.  couldn't you loop on `bucket` in `MapItr` and just ignore null entries?

### 3) Best Practices

1. References to generic type `Entity<K,T>` should be parameterized: Throughout the code, you refer to the `Entity` raw type, without the `<K, T>` generic parameters.  While it seems that this should not produce a bug, (since `add()` method only accept args of the correct types, this is still considered bad practice (and indeed produces compile warning).
2. The use of `Objects.nonNull()` is redundant.  why not use the simple and clear `node != null`? and while we are there, you first assign `node` to `result` and then ask about null. so theoretically, you could return null result.

### 4) Naming Conventions

1. an array of buckets should be named `buckets` or perhaps `bucket_array` don't you think?

Comment: Thank you so much for such valuable comments, I started working on listed items and will share the updated code once I done with all points.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to fix.

1. `Entity` should be private and nested.
2. `Entity<K, T> next` is valid field inside Entity.java, you are using generics.
3. `<K, V>` is a more standard name than `<K, T>`
4. `Entity[] bucket = null;` can be marked as final.
5. You dont need a private `init`, a constructor can call another constructor, called constructor overloading.
6. `hash` method does not check for `null`
7. `add` can be renamed to `put`
8. In `add`, `System.arraycopy(obj, 0, bucket, 0, indexCount-1);` is BUGGY. You need to rehash and recalculate index.
9. In `add` you are advancing temp. Its giving you no benefit. Infact it appears buggy. Try looking up for stack using linkedlist.
10. In `get`, your if statement is redundant. code works perfectly fine without if block

10.Your `delete` is `buggy`. If you assign null to a bucket then you lost all others mapped to that bucket.

11. Your

`count++;
   if (count < bucketItr.length)
        node = bucketItr[count];`

Shoud be a while, and while until node !=  null.